# Need key code for Alt-Ctrl-Del

Tags: c#

I need the key code for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in c#,
for example

```
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;      
keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event(0x11, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); 
keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

this is the code for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is used by the operating system (I remember from the the old days, even the BIOS).

So I don't think you can use it in C#, not even for sending the keystrokes.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot capture <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. It's captured by the operating system and is **very** secure.

Even programs like VMWare have to emulate it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> since Windows protects it so well, and for good reason. If you could subvert it, Windows login security would be useless.